# QT Making a Dropdown Menu Widget Programmatically

Tags: c++, qt, drop-down-menu, widget

I am using QT 5.5 with Mac OSX. I want to make several dropdown menu widgets programmatically that will have various options that can change the values of certain variables.

So for example, I would have dropdown menu 1 represent variable "command" have:
- Q
- W
- E
- R
And by selecting whichever one, then it would make command = Q, or command = W. So that way, I can send command to another program knowing that I sent Q, or W.

My current mainwindow looks something like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
//******* Set up
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->centralWidget->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);

// 01: Creation of Console
console = new Console;
console->setEnabled(false);

/************** Adding Widgets *********************/
//creation and attribution of slider
slider = new QSlider();
slider->resize(255, 20);
slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
slider->setRange(0, 255); //0-255 is range we can read

//creation and attribution of the lcd
lcd = new QLCDNumber();
lcd->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
lcd->resize(255, 50);

//03: Adding widgets to layout
//add console as a widget to the main widget
//layout with slider and lcd underneath console
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(console);
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(slider);
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(lcd);

////////I WANT TO ADD VARIOUS DROPDOWN MENUS HERE NEXT TO EACH OTHER//////// 

/************** Connection Events ***********************/
....
```

}

Comment: By drop down menu, do you mean a ComboBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want a ComboBox, Here is how you can do it:

```
QStringList commands = { "Q", "W", "E", "R" };
QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox(this);
combo->addItems(commands);
connect( combo, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, this, &MainWindow::commandChanged);
```

Now you will get the command text when user changes the combo box item. and you can write your code based on that.

```
MainWindow::commandChanged(const QString& command_text)
{
    //Do the logic based on command_text
}
```

Another option if you want to choose combobox item texts differently is that you set [`itemData`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qcombobox.html#addItem) for combobox items. and get them in your slot by [`currentData`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop) property of the ComboBox.